# If Vlookup returns Error, then how to Increment the table array

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I am trying to do vlookup, but however it is matching only first row and my return value is always at last Column (reason).

```
=vlookup(H:H,A:F,6,0)
```

I tried with Match and Index functions, but it's not looking up for values other than first column.

[image: Lookup array and results in screenshot]

I know the vlookup will not work, but any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this shorter formula.

In `I2` enter array formula and copied down :

```
=INDEX(F:F,SUM((IFNA($A$2:$E$6,"")=H2)*ROW($A$2:$E$6)))
```

This is an array formula and needs to be confirmed by pressing with <kbd>Ctl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try `INDEX`/`AGGREGATE` combination:

```
=INDEX($F$2:$F$6,AGGREGATE(15,6,(1/(H2=$A$2:$E$6))*ROW($F$2:$F$6)-1,1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it's working. But i didn't understand how ?

Comment: ```H2=$A$2:$E$6``` returns an array with bool values - ```TRUE``` if ```H2``` is found, ```FALSE``` if not. Dividing an one by this array, we get an array with 1's and an #DIV/0! values, which is then multiplied by ```ROW (...)``` to get an array with row numbers and error values. The ```AGGREGATE``` function with parameters ```15``` and ```6``` then returns the smallest row number ignoring the errors. By passing this value to the ```INDEX``` function, we obtain the corresponding value in column ```F```.